# convertir texto de un array a mayúsculas intercalado

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo el siguiente código y lo que quiero hacer es que tenga un texto y que se ponga en mayúsculas una letra y otra no(intercalado), intente creando un nuevo array y luego unirlo

```js
//el = element
//variables linkeadas al html(pueden ser redefinidas(componentes reactivos))
let app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        link: "https://google.com",
        navegador: "Google",
        nombre: "Jonathan",
        saludo: "Hola",
        estado: "Como estas?",
        mostrar: true,
        mostrar1: true, 
        titulo: "Texto",
        subtitulo: "SuBItiUlO",
        subsubtitulo: "caPitAliZE aSaA",
        intercalado: "intercalado"
    },
    filters: {
        mayuscula: function(str){
            return str.toUpperCase()
        },
        lowerCase: function(str){
            return str.toLowerCase()
        },
        capitalize: function(str){
            return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase()
        },
        toggle: function(str){
            for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                var y = str.split("")
                var x = []
                
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    x[i] = y[i].toUpperCase()
                }
                else{
                    x[i] = y[i].toLowerCase()

                }
                document.write(x.join(""))
            
                console.log(y[i].toUpperCase())
                debugger
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Vue.js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        {{saludo}} {{ nombre }}, {{estado}}.
        <h1 v-if="mostrar">{{titulo | mayuscula}}</h1>
        <h2>{{subtitulo | lowerCase}}</h2>
        <h2>{{subsubtitulo | capitalize}}</h2>
        <h3>{{intercalado | toggle}}</h3>
        <a v-if="mostrar" v-bind:href="link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{{navegador}}</a>
        <template v-if="mostrar1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
            Cumque fuga, natus ut temporibus esse doloribus tenetur? 
            Doloribus minus 
            amet facere, modi illo 
            molestias libero atque doloremque earum ut minima ipsam!
        </template>
    </div>

        
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

todo, pero no me da resultado, alguna idea?

Comment: no estas retornando el resultado en tu filtro

Comment: En x esta tu texto intercalado. Pero no forma parte del data, ni de ninguna variable en el data, por lo tanto, no lo estas mostrando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varios errores en tu filtro.

Por ejemplo la variable `x` la vuelves a crear en cada iteración por tanto aunque la retornes vendrá solo con la ultima letra. Ademas de ello no posees la sentencia `return` que retorna el resultado de tu filtro y no es necesario realizar un `document.write`.

Te recomiendo que realices esto:

```js
let str = 'Palabra';
str = str.toLowerCase().split('').map((word, index) => {
    if (index % 2 === 0) {
        return word.toUpperCase()
    }
    return word
}).join('')
console.log(str)
```

Pon dentro de tu filtro el código que mapea la palabra y luego retorna el resultado (Obvia el `str` es solo el ejemplo para comprobar el funcionamiento)